# Show that if $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n (z-a)^n$ on $B(a,R)$, then $f'(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}na_n(z-a)^{n-1}$ on $B(a,R)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

What I have so far is using the Cauchy Integral Formula $f'(a)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{B(a,R)}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(\zeta - a)^n / (\zeta - a)^2 d\zeta=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{B(a,R)}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(\zeta - a)^{n-2}d\zeta$. Not really sure where to go from here?

EDIT: This was my final result,

Using Cauchy Integral Formula gives,

$f'(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial B(a,R)}\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^2}d\zeta$.

Now, using the analyticity of $f$, substitute in $f(\zeta)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(\zeta-a)^n$. This will yield,

$f'(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial B(a,R)}\frac{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(\zeta-a)^n}{(\zeta-z)^2}d\zeta$.

Now since the power series for $f$ converges in $B(a,R)$ then then it converges uniformly for $\overline{B}(a,\rho)$ with $\rho<R$. Thus,

$f'(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial B(a,\rho)}\frac{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(\zeta-a)^n}{(\zeta-z)^2}d\zeta=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial B(a,\rho)}\frac{(\zeta-a)^n}{(\zeta-z)^2}d\zeta=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n[(\zeta-a)^n]'=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n\cdot n(\zeta-a)^{n-1}$.

Since this converges and is $f'$ for all $\rho<R$, it converges on $B(a,R)$.

Comment: A power series may be differentiated term-by-term in its region of convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the power series for $f(z)$ converges on $B(a,R)$, then it converges uniformly on $B(a,\rho)$ for all $0<\rho <R$.  We also have for $z\in B(a,\rho)$, uniform convergence of the series

$$g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty n\,a_n(z-z_0)^{n-1}$$

Therefore, we have $f'(z)=g(z)$ for $z\in B(a,\rho)$, which holds for every $0<\rho<R$.  Therefore, we have $f$ is differentiable on $B(a,R)$ and $f'=g$.

Comment: Thanks for the help! How do you know $g(z)$ converges in the ball of radius $\rho$?

Comment: The Hadamard radius formula. The radius  of convergence of $\sum a_nz^n$ is $1/\lim \sup ( |a_n|^{1/n})$.

Comment: We know it converges by the ratio test.